# Listing all devices connected to a simple router remotely

Tags: router, wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

I have two simple routers given to me by my ISP. One is Technicolor TC7200 and the other one is Thomson TWG870UG. I would like to remotely list all of the devices connected to the router (their IP and MAC addresses). By remotely I mean that I would like to do it from my computer connected to the same network(router) either by WLAN or an Ethernet cable.

I need it, because I would like to run a simple app on my computer which would periodically list all of the devices connected to the network.

The only way to (partially) achieve this, I've already discovered, is to log to the router's administrator panel, where I can find all of the connected devices listed. The problem with this method is that it is impossible(?) to export the data anywhere.

My question is - is there any way to extract these data directly from the router (It would be fine if I get all of the packets going through the router too).

If not, is there any reliable way to do it remotely from my (linux) computer, other than sniffing the network and analyzing the packets using eg. Wireshark software?

Comment: I have serious doubts whether this kind of setup is really suitable for a business environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting that kind of data from the router itself might be tricky, if the router doesn't have a good interface for you to do it on.

Failing that, I'd say just fire up [nmap](https://nmap.org/) and do either a ping scan or an ARP scan of the network - if you want to integrate that with another application, there's an XML output option that you could run on a schedule and parse.

Comment: Will the `nmap` give me the:
1. list of all devices connected to the router;
2. list of all devices in the range of the device(computer) on which I will use this command;
3. devices which ever established some sort of communication with the device(computer) on which I will use this command?

Comment: Devices on the subnet, which (unless your network topology is more complex than just one subnet on one layer 2 segment) will effectively be all devices connected to the router (plus the router itself).

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt Yup, I was answering based on that assumption in the question, `By remotely I mean that I would like to do it from my computer connected to the same network(router) either by WLAN or an Ethernet cable`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the router's administrator panel is implemented you may be able to retrieve the page containing the list of connected devices with an appropriately crafted `wget` command. Check out `wget` options `--user` and `--password`. You can then extract the list from the resulting HTML file with tools like `sed`, `awk` or `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

I use Lan Scan on my mac not sure if they make it for windows and it can export to excel. Show IP mac address and manufacturer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.